# How to make the TTS to read all the Listview items by clicking it only once?

Tags: android, android-listview, text-to-speech

I have a Listview in android that can be read by TTS when you click the items it reads it, but my problem is how to make the TTS to read all the items by clicking any of the items in the listview only once?

here's the codes

```
 package learn2crack.listview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



import learn2crack.listview.library.JSONParser;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
ListView list;
TextView html;
Button Btngetdata;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

//URL to get JSON Array
private static String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=New%20York,NY&sensor=false"; //url is just a sample

//JSON Node Names 
private static final String TAG_OS = "routes";
private static final String TAG_HTM = "html_instructions";
private TextToSpeech myTTS;
private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;

JSONArray android = null;

 public void onInit(int initStatus) {

        // check for successful instantiation
        if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            if (myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US) == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
                myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        } else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



    Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
    Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             new JSONParse().execute();


        }
    });


}


private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
     private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
         html = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.html_instruction);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();



    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
         pDialog.dismiss();
         try {
                // Getting JSON Array from URL
                android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
                for (int x = 0; x < android.length(); x++) {
                    JSONArray legs = android.getJSONObject(x).getJSONArray("legs");
                    JSONObject distance = legs.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("distance");
                    JSONObject duration = legs.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("duration");
                    JSONArray steps = legs.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("steps");

                    for (int j = 0; j < steps.length(); j++) {
                            String html_instructions = steps.getJSONObject(j).getString("html_instructions");
                            String s = html_instructions.replaceAll("<(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^'\">])*>", " ");




                //for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                //JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                //String ver = c.getString(TAG_VER);
                //String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                //String api = c.getString(TAG_API);
                //String htm = c.getString("html_instructions");



                // Adding value HashMap key => value


                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                map.put(TAG_HTM, s);

                oslist.add(map);
                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);





                final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
                        R.layout.list_v,
                        new String[] {TAG_HTM}, new int [] {R.id.html_instruction});

                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
                checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
                startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {



                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+position).get("html"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        parent.getAdapter();
                        //adapter.getItem(position).toString();
                        String words = adapter.getItem(position).toString();
                       //  String words = html.getText().toString();
                        speakWords(words);

                    }
                    private void speakWords(String speech) {
                        //speak straight away
                        myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }

                });


                }
        }} catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



     }
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            //the user has the necessary data - create the TTS
        myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this,(OnInitListener) this);
        }
        else {
                //no data - install it now
            Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
            installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installTTSIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This could be as simple as looping through the backing dataset and passing the relevant phrase for every item to the tts engine. Is there any particular step you're having trouble with? Perhaps you can show us some code that illustrates what you have & haven't got working so far?

Comment: TTS ???????????????????

Comment: @greenapps Text To Speech

Comment: @MH here's the code got any ideas?

Comment: @user3103990L just iterate over the items in the adapter, but use `TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD` to make sure all the phrases you're adding get synthesized, as documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#QUEUE_ADD).